# Separate SELECT into multiple columns by WHERE condition without creating multiple rows caused by adding to GROUP BY

Tags: sql, syntax, sybase

I'm trying to split SUM( trs_amt ) and SELECT it into 'trs_sum' column when trs_trust_code is either 1 or 2, and into an 'interest' column when trs_trust_code = 9. I cant seem to figure out how to do it without creating an extra row when adding trs_trust_code to the GROUP BY. I have tried a CASE in SELECT, a CASE in GROUP BY, subqueries

```
SELECT
    trs_desk,
    dsk_name,
    DATEPART( YEAR, DATEADD( DAY, trs_trx_date, '1600-12-31' ) ) as 'year',
    DATEPART( MONTH, DATEADD( DAY, trs_trx_date, '1600-12-31' ) ) as 'month',
    COUNT( DISTINCT trs_amt ) AS 'trs_count',
    SUM( trs_amt ) AS 'trs_sum',
    SUM( trs_comm_amt ) AS 'trs_comm_sum'
FROM cds.trs
JOIN cds.dsk on dsk_code = trs_desk
WHERE trs_desk IN ( 'ACE' )
AND trs_trust_code IN ('1','2','9')
GROUP BY trs_desk, year, month, dsk_name
ORDER BY trs_desk ASC, year DESC, month DESC
```

Comment: The question is not clear, can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the expression *case when trs_trust_code = 9 then trs_amt else 0 end* in the sum. For example like this:

```
SELECT
    trs_desk,
    dsk_name,
    DATEPART( YEAR, DATEADD( DAY, trs_trx_date, '1600-12-31' ) ) as 'year',
    DATEPART( MONTH, DATEADD( DAY, trs_trx_date, '1600-12-31' ) ) as 'month',
    COUNT( DISTINCT trs_amt ) AS 'trs_count',
    SUM( case when trs_trust_code = 1 or trs_trust_code = 2 then trs_amt else 0 end ) AS 'trs_sum',
    SUM( case when trs_trust_code = 9 then trs_amt else 0 end ) AS 'interest',
    SUM( trs_comm_amt ) AS 'trs_comm_sum'
FROM cds.trs
JOIN cds.dsk on dsk_code = trs_desk
WHERE trs_desk IN ( 'ACE' )
AND trs_trust_code IN ('1','2','9')
GROUP BY trs_desk, year, month, dsk_name
ORDER BY trs_desk ASC, year DESC, month DESC
```

Comment: YES. thank you so much. it was the OR that did it. I had in('1','2'). or maybe I had the SUM inside the CASE